# Как разделить Swipe экрана на 50/25% Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d, touch

Доброго времени суток, не могу понять как правильно разделить свайп экрана,  не получается найти 25% экрана по ширине, объяснение на рисунке

1) Короткий свайп (25 размерность если брать то что размер экрана равняется 100)

2) Длинный свайп (50)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт с моими попытками:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using System;
public class TouchGesture
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GestureSettings
    {
        public float minSwipeDist = 100;
        public float maxSwipeTime = 10;
    //  public float minSwipeDist25 = 50;
//      public float maxSwipeTime25 = 10;
    }
    private GestureSettings settings;
    private float swipeStartTime;
    private bool couldBeSwipe;
    private Vector2 startPos;
    private int stationaryForFrames;
    private TouchPhase lastPhase;
    public TouchGesture(GestureSettings gestureSettings)
    {
        this.settings = gestureSettings;
    }
    public IEnumerator CheckHorizontalSwipes(Action onLeftSwipe50, Action onLeftSwipe25, Action onRightSwipe50,Action onRightSwipe25) //Coroutine, which gets Started in "Start()" and runs over the whole game to check for swipes
    {
        while (true)
        { 
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            { //For every touch in the Input.touches - array...
                switch (touch.phase)
                {
                case TouchPhase.Began: //The finger first touched the screen --> It could be(come) a swipe
                    couldBeSwipe = true;
                    startPos = touch.position;  //Position where the touch started
                    swipeStartTime = Time.time; //The time it started
                    stationaryForFrames = 0;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Stationary: //Is the touch stationary? --> No swipe then!
                    if (isContinouslyStationary(frames:6))
                        couldBeSwipe = false;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    if (isASwipe(touch))
                    {
                        couldBeSwipe = false; //<-- Otherwise this part would be called over and over again.
                        if (TouchDistance1(touch.position.x - startPos.x) == 1f ) //Swipe-direction, either 1 or -1.   

                            onRightSwipe50(); //Right-swipe
                        else if (TouchDistance(touch.position.x - startPos.x) == 0.5f ) //Swipe-direction, either 0,5 or -0,5.  
                            onRightSwipe25(); //Right-swipe

                        else if (TouchDistance1(touch.position.x - startPos.x) == -1f ) //Swipe-direction, either 1 or -1.  
                            onLeftSwipe50(); //Left-swipe

                        else if (TouchDistance(touch.position.x - startPos.x) == -0.5f )  //Swipe-direction, either 0,5 or -0,5.  
                            onLeftSwipe25(); //Right-swipe
                    }
                    break;
                }
                lastPhase = touch.phase;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private bool isContinouslyStationary(int frames)
    {
        if (lastPhase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            stationaryForFrames++;
        else // reset back to 1
            stationaryForFrames = 1;
        return stationaryForFrames > frames;
    }
    private bool isASwipe(Touch touch)
    {
        float swipeTime = Time.time - swipeStartTime; //Time the touch stayed at the screen till now.
        float swipeDist = Mathf.Abs(touch.position.x - startPos.x); //Swipe distance
    //  return couldBeSwipe && swipeTime < settings.maxSwipeTime && (swipeDist > settings.minSwipeDist || swipeDist < settings.minSwipeDist25); 
        return couldBeSwipe && swipeTime < settings.maxSwipeTime && swipeDist > settings.minSwipeDist;
    }

    static float TouchDistance( float f)
    {
        return f < 0 ? -0.5f : (f > 0 ? 0.5f : 0);
    }

    static float TouchDistance1( float f)
    {
        return f < 0 ? -1 : (f > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Скрипт2:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class swipetouching : MonoBehaviour {

    public TouchGesture.GestureSettings GestureSetting;
    private TouchGesture touch;
    public Text swipe;
    void Start()
    {
        touch = new TouchGesture(this.GestureSetting);
        StartCoroutine(touch.CheckHorizontalSwipes(
            onLeftSwipe50: () => { HideMenuHome50(); },
            onLeftSwipe25: () => { HideMenuHome25(); },
            onRightSwipe50: () => { ShowMenuHome50(); },
            onRightSwipe25: () => { ShowMenuHome25(); }
        ));
    }

    void HideMenuHome50()
    {
        Debug.Log ("swipe left 50");
        swipe.text = "swipe left 50";
    }

    void ShowMenuHome50()
    {
        Debug.Log ("swipe right 50");
        swipe.text = "swipe right 50";
    }
    void HideMenuHome25()
    {

        Debug.Log ("swipe left 25");
        swipe.text = "swipe left  25";
    }

    void ShowMenuHome25()
    {
        Debug.Log ("swipe right 25");
        swipe.text = "swipe right 25";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Screen.width*0.25>=Mathf.abs(touch.position.x - startPos.x). Это для 25% горизонтального свайпа. Ну и 0.25 меняем на 0.5, будет 50%. Если надо чтобы свайп ровно 25%, то можно проверку с двух сторон устроить например <26 но >24